# Authentication by using Tomcat LDAPs and PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, tomcat7

currently I am working with Tomcat 7 and PHP to create active directory login.

A bit description about the system:

It is based on PHP and running on Tomcat 7. What I want is to connect Tomcat 7 LDAPs with PHP. Is there a way to do so? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that. Use Tomcat 7's [built-in support for SPNEGO authentication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html)

Also running PHP on Tomcat 7 is a risky enterprise at best. You'd be much better off running your PHP app on Apache httpd.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But why can't I even just enable the ldap extension? Everytime I try to enabled the ldap extension, tomcat server always return error: library not found? FYI, I have add the 3 .dll file, but it still did not work.

Comment: What extension? How have you enabled it? What 3 .dll files? Is that the complete error message? Define "did not work".

Comment: The extension is php_ldap.dll. It is an extension from php and usually when we want to use it we just need to add "extension=php_ldap.dll" in php.ini file. And as I read, to run ldap on php, we need to either add the libsasl.dll, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to windows PATH environment or move it to php folder. As I tried to do both ways, it still did not work for me. And yes, it is all the error that I found. Did not work here means, php can not load the extension, it shows when I tried to use function from ldap, e.g. ldap_connect, it will return error like "ldap_connect is not a function".

Comment: and just for your information, this error only happened when I load it on tomcat server. Before I have tried to do the same and run it on my apache server and it works perfectly. But, because of company rule and company environment, it is a must to deploy it on tomcat server.

Comment: As I said, trying to run PHP on Tomcat is a risky enterprise. The standard advice (and I say this with my Tomcat committer hat on) is don't do that - use httpd.